# SELECTing (almost) duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

My table looks something like this:

```
| id (int) | sentence (varchar) |
```

I want to find all rows that are almost the same except for one particular word. Eg:

```
| 230 | test |
| 321 | test sth |
...
| 329 | is (sth) it?
| 923 | is it?
```

The word that can be different is *sth* in this case. Ideally I could use some sort of "array" with the list of words that can be different.

Is this something I could do purely in SQL?

Comment: full text search and sort by relevance? basic sql is totally crappy for "fuzzy" string matching like this.

Comment: FYI: There is a link to the official [MySQL regex documentaiton](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), listed under "General Documentation > Official documentation for specific flavors > Databases".

Comment: Does "the same except for one particular word" mean "the particular word can be present or absent" or does it mean "the particular word might be different / misspelled / replaced with any other word but the rest of the sentence stays the same" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an untested quick shot, sorry, but I think you could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY REPLACE(text, 'sth', '')
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you want to remove *every* occurrence of `'sth'` from *every* record.  Plus your select list should probably aggregate over `id`, e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`.

Comment: This query should not modify anything. What do you mean by "remove"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SOUNDEX`. So with the *examples* that you gave, these queries:

```
SELECT SOUNDEX('test')
SELECT SOUNDEX('test sth')
SELECT SOUNDEX('is (sth) it?')
SELECT SOUNDEX('is it?')
```

return these results:

```
T230
T230
I200
I200
```

That means that the *first two* and the *second two* **sound like** each other. What I can't be sure of is how well this will work with your **actual** data, you're just going to have to *try it.*

Comment: I get `SOUNDEX('test sth') = 'T2323'` and `SOUNDEX('is (sth) it?') = SOUNDEX ('is it?') = 'I230'` :/

Comment: @eggyal, hmm, I'm not sure I can explain that per say except that does `SOUNDEX('test')` get `T2323` or `T230`?

Comment: I get `SOUNDEX('test') = 'T230'`.  See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a0f6/1/0).